# Site's Beta Graduation

Tags: discussion, graduation

Today I came across this post on the Movies & TV Meta:

[900 days in beta: Where do we stand?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1267/900-days-in-beta-where-do-we-stand).

And a moderator posted this:

> Well I'm pleased to echo Robert Cartaino's comment below that
>   Movies.SE is slated for graduation.

Looking at the Movies & TV Area 51 Statistics, you can see that they have

- 3/5 Excellent
- 2/5 Okay

Whereas Musical Practice & Performance has:

- 4/5 Excellent
- 1/5 Okay

This site has less QPD, but way better Answer Ration (1.1 more).

So are we going to graduate soon as well?

Comment: Those five criteria aren't all that are taken into account. Movies.SE has almost 2.5x the daily views that we get. (And it's not just Movies.SE -- there are quite a few beta sites that have graduated with area51 stats that are less than ours, if you search the ["launched" tab](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched).)

Comment: I think this answer likely still holds: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/a/589/8682. It seems we haven't reached critical mass (definition of this is not known).

Comment: @NReilingh: The Movies & TV should have lots more visitors than this one, concerning the width of the scope. That isn't saying we could have more visits though...

Comment: @NReilingh So, what judges when a beta will graduate? Looking at the [RPG.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games) statistics, they weren't so good as this site

Comment: SE decides on a per site basis.  I don't think they'll give us any more specifics than they have in the past years, even if this new trend of begging for graduation every week continues.

Comment: The other thing to consider is that A51 stats are frozen at the time of launch, so they may have been growing much faster than we are.

Comment: We all want this site to graduate and it is frustrating not knowing what can be done to accelerate the process,  but as long as we keep getting new questions and growing active users base we will eventually graduate.

Comment: @Dom, Meaningful and Shev: There are several Meta questions that address what we can do to increase our chances for graduation including http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/584/im-going-to-print-up-some-flyers-to-distribute-at-music-colleges

Answer (score 2):

From similar discussions in the Code Golf meta, another significant criterion is the number of high-rep users (10k+) who can still access the moderator tools and help with the review queues after graduation.

Comment: Really good point...