# How long has this Site been in beta?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering how long this site has been in beta because I have been a part of it for a year now, also when will it become an "official site" (for want of a better term) like Super User and Stack Exchange? I believe it has a good enough and high enough following for it to be out of Beta by now or am I making a big deal over nothing?

Comment: Actually, ignore my answer - this question is a duplicate of one of the ones I linked, so I'll close as dupe.

Comment: If you haven't seen it yet, [this page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4059/musical-practice-and-performance) has our beta statistics, including number of days in beta.

Answer (score 3):

We started private beta in April 2011, and public beta in May of that year. Some sites have been in beta much longer than us. And some had to be a bit bigger before they graduated.

As you can see from a couple of other questions on this topic, we are doing well, growth is good, the stats show we are getting to a healthy position, and my hope is that graduation is not far off.

- [Site's Beta Graduation](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/796/104)
- [So why is this site still in beta?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/534/104)

Things you can do to help:

- publicise the site. To your friends, on music forums etc. If someone asks you a question that could fit on here, ask it and then give them the link so they can check it and any answers out.
- ask more questions
- answer questions